# Foreach Loop to supress duplicate but add values

Tags: php

Hope someone can help.

I have this array (this is a only a snippet as there is loads of lines). I have been trying to do this myself today.

```
array(628) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "User 1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "User 2"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "User 1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "User 3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "User 3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "User 4"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "User 1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "User 5"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "User 3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "User 1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "User 5"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

As you can see there is duplicate "Users" they wont be called User #. I would like any duplicates gone but the values of [1] added togather and also values of [2] added together also.

Hope that information helps

Thanks

```html
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "User 1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "37"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "User 2"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "User 3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "38"
   }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "User 5"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
```

Comment: post the desired result

Comment: "I have been trying to do this myself today.", do please share what you  have tried

Comment: I have added the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array ('User 1', 10, 10),
                1 => array ('User 2', 10, 10),
                2 => array ('User 1', 10, 10),
                3 => array ('User 2', 10, 10),
                4 => array ('User 1', 10, 10),
                5 => array ('User 3', 10, 10),
); 
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $val){
    $key = array_search($val[0], array_column($result, 0));
    if($key !== false){
        $result[$key][1] = $result[$key][1] + $val[1];
        $result[$key][2] = $result[$key][2] + $val[2];
    }else{
        $result[] = $val;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

[Code Snippet](https://3v4l.org/DWCgn)

Comment: This is brilliant! Learnt something